# PhantomJS hostfile change or host header

Tags: javascript, localhost, phantomjs, virtualhost, ab-testing

I want to write PhantomJS script that allow testing on localhost version and production version of a website (localhost need host name to resolve, cannot work on ip address). The script basically just compare between two version: load local version, render to image, load production version, render to image and compare those two. What I am doing now is using host file which require a lot of modify and saving host file (not so good solution because it affect others and sometime it was cached)

There is another way is using host header for example:

prod: http://example.com

local: http://127.0.01/ with host: example.com

which have same result with hostfile and more safe. The problem is only the main html is loaded with local version, resource, css, image static is load using 127.0.0.1 which cannot resolve....

My question is: how can I tell PhantomJS to use host header for all request?

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer :D, by intercept resourceRequest event, we can change url or header of resource.

```js
var targetHost=  'example.com'; 
var targetIP = '127.0.0.1'; 
var page = require('webpage').create(); 
page.onResourceRequested = function(request, network){   //Intercept request here, change url,header.   
  var newUrl = request.url.replace(targetHost, targetIP);  
  console.log('Intercepted change url to ', newUrl, targetHost);  
  network.setHeader('Host', targetHost); 
  network.changeUrl(newUrl); 
};
page.open(url, function() {});
```